# C++11x and Eigen library

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

I want to compile a program, where I initialize a complex matrix `MatrixXcd` in Eigen using

```
MatrixXcd M;
M.resize(length,length);

M(i,j).real()=f(i,j)
M(i,j).imag()=f(i,j)
```

where f(i,j) is some function of type `std::complex<double>` of i,j. It all works fine, unless I use the `-std=c++0x` compiler option, which I do need. When using this option, I get the error:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

For the above line of code, what is going wrong?

Comment: The message say `M(i,j).real()` is not a (modifiable) lvalue, so you can't assign to it.  What is the result of `M(i,j).real()`?

Comment: What is `M`? Is its element type `std::complex<double>`?

Comment: I edited my question to answer the comment. I do understand what the error message says, however the assignment works fine if I don't use the -std=c++x option, only with this option the error message appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
M(i, j) = f(i, j);
```

That's already assigning the real part only.

If you want to assign a general complex number given its real and imaginary parts, use e.g.

```
M(i, j) = std::complex<double>(f(i, j), g(i, j));
```